# Removing the same file from multiple commits so that it's not in the PR

Tags: git, github

I use a JS framework that builds a large bundle file. For testing purposes, I built and committed the bundle so that I could test the changes on a test server. I have a handful of commits that include this bundle, `main.js`, in it but my manager prefers not to merge the bundles in. When creating the PR, how can I exclude this file.

I don't want to delete it because it exists on `master`. But I want to act it if I never added that file change in all of the commits

Comment: The simplest way is, to create a new branch, without this undesirable files and make there a Pull Request...

Answer (score 0):

I understood the following : file `main.js` exists on `master`, and if you had followed the guidelines, it would never have been modified it on your branch.
You would like to have your PR not mention file `main.js` as a modified file.

---

If this is indeed what you are looking for : just restore file `main.js` to the content it had in `master`, when your branch forked :

```
# find the merge base which github will use for your PR :
git merge-base master my/branch

# use the sha1 above to restore main.js :
git checkout <merge-base> -- main.js
git commit
git push
```

File `main.js` should not appear as modified in your PR.